# .htaccess rewrite changes error url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have made some redirecting stuff in my .htaccess and it works quiet well.

```
RewriteEngine On
# add www. if missing
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
# redirect index.html and index.php to the simple homepage
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\|/index\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$|^index\.html$ http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]
# add trailing slash if missing
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*[^/]$ /$0/ [L,R=301]
# redirect simulated directories to php files of the same name in /content/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(\/css|\/images) [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ content/$1\.php?rw=1 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^rw=1
RewriteRule ^content/([^/]+).php$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

But while the part that adds trailing slashes is enabled there is a strange issue with urls that don't exist and that are directed to my 404 error page:
For example, if I enter www.example.com/notexisting/ that url is transformed to www.example.com/content/notexisting.php/?rw=1
This does not happen when I disable the part for trailing slashes or the one for simulated directories in htaccess. But I want to keep both. Is there a possibility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you can quite easily fix your problem by adding an extra condition to your 'slash' redirect. You don't seem to have any url's that end on .php, so you can check if your url already ends with that. If that is not the case, you can add the slash.

```
RewriteEngine On

# add www. if missing
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# redirect index.html and index.php to the simple homepage
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\|/index\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$|^index\.html$ http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]

# add trailing slash if missing
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$
RewriteRule ^.*[^/]$ /$0/ [L,R=301]

# redirect simulated directories to php files of the same name in /content/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(\/css|\/images) [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ content/$1\.php?rw=1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^rw=1
RewriteRule ^content/([^/]+).php$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```